# using a TVS in place of a zenner diode

Tags: diodes, zener, tvs

I have read somewhere that a TVS is nothing else than a robust Zener diode. My application requires using 300V zener diodes (that may exist but do not pop up so easily), but TVS at 300V are very common and inexpensive. My question is: can TVS diode be used to regulate the voltage in reverse mode like a usual Zener diode would do ?

Comment: See this thread, maybe it helps https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233600/differences-between-tvs-diode-and-zener-diodes-in-diagrams-and-in-practice

Comment: An ideal one could. In practice, I'd question the precision of the breakdown voltage; it seems unlikely that TVS diodes, which are made to stop fault conditions, would require as precise a breakdown voltage as Zener/avalanche diodes, which are made to be voltage references.

Comment: Google "The XY Problem stack exchange", read that and decide whether you might want to explain why you think you need a 300V zener diode.

Comment: You can read this article and see why I want 300V zener diode: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.885.9903&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @MikeTeX Thank you for sharing a good article. Are you working on free energy machine?

Comment: @eugene-bright. Not at all, sorry.

Comment: Never mind. But it's good time to have one...