# How to use bi-directional polarity diode?

Tags: diodes

I'm playing with 5V circuit and would like to block current in one direction so I'm thinking naturally to use a diode, the only basic part on JLCB I found is [SMF30CA](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2205231816_Liown-SMF30CA_C2990493.pdf) which is bi-directional.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvM8ch.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So would like to know what is the purpose of bi-directional in diode if it's mean what is think (allow current on both way).

If I can still use it I guess there is no specific direct when place it in circuit?

Comment: You should give us more description about your circuit and what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to block the 9V battery while you have the 5V from a power supply, and then allow current from the 9V battery into the circuit once the supply is off? The circuit as you drew it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That part isn't even in the diode section, it's listed as a TVS. Which it is.

Comment: @EdinFifić i was just doing some testing. I'm trying to measure the 5V power source from the MCU without any interference from the 9V power source. But essentially I just would like to understand and know when we need to use bi-directionnal diode.

Comment: @hobbs oops, but it's look like TVS are still diodes right?

Comment: @Unicorn That measurement can be done according to the schematic you drew. But the "bi-directional diode" is a overvoltage/spike protection device which can be made out of 2 zener diodes back-to-back or purchased as a single TVS (Transient Voltage Suppressor) device/diode, as "hobbs" has mentioned above.

Comment: @Unicorn sorta but you wouldn't use them in most places you would use diodes :) They're roughly like two diodes "back to back", and you put them someplace where you want to conduct (basically make a short circuit) any time the voltage goes over a certain level, positive or negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principal, every diode is bidirectional.

**(1)** `Every Diode has a Forward-Voltage.` This is the voltage which must be applied from `Anode to Kathode` in order to conduct `significant currents`. This voltage is generally very low. It varies with the type of diode used. Generally, `0.7V` is assumed.

**(2)** `Every Diode has a Breakdown-Voltage.` This is the voltage which must be exceeded from `Kathode to Anode` in order to conduct `significant currents`. This voltage is generally high. It varies with the type of diode used and the model selected. Some Diodes are made for High-Voltage DC-Applications, while others are made for small-signal applications. Some are made for AC-Rectification, some are made for TVS.

**(3)** The Diode you selected, see [Datasheet SMF30CA](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2205231816_Liown-SMF30CA_C2990493.pdf), is a so-called `TVS-Diode`. These diodes are used to `protect signal and/or power lines` from so-called transient events - better known as `ESD events`. Please see [Discussion about TVS Diodes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233600/differences-between-tvs-diode-and-zener-diodes-in-diagrams-and-in-practice).

`If you need` a "conventional Diode", please use a standard PN-Type like [1N400X Series](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf).

These are available as SMD-Types as well.

Comment: Ok, it's clearer now. thanks

Comment: @Unicorn You are welcome!